# Android ViewPager and Fade Transitions

Tags: android, android-animation, android-viewpager

I am trying to create a ViewPager (using the Compatibility Package and Gingerbread) that would fade in/out gradually between view transitions. The default view transition has a slide effect. Fade transitions could be accomplished using ViewFlipper or ViewSwitcher, but I would like to know what effort would be required to get it working with a ViewPager.

Comment: Good luck! Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: The time effort involved in finding a solution wasn't worth it for me, so I moved on to other things.